# sum([.25,.35,.3,.1,0]) gives 0.999999(9) instead of 1. Why?

Tags: python

This is a very basic sum of 5 floats. It's very obvious that the result is 1, so why does python shows me `0.9999999` when i print the result?

```
sum([.25,.35,.3,.1,0]) # gives 0.999999(9)
```

Comment: From the 5 numbers you want to add, only 2 are exactly representable as binary64 floating point numbers. Hence the sum cannot be 1 unless the rounding errors compensate. Generally, when a floating point operation returns a perfect number, it is most likely pure luck unless the numbers are designed to do so.

Comment: Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point